Why does `Option::map` work with immutable data, but not with mutable data
Why does the immutable version in the following example work, but the mutable version does not compile with error error: lifetime may not live long enough?
trait Car {
    fn honk(&self);
}

struct CarCollection {
    cars: HashMap<usize, Box<dyn Car>>,
}

impl CarCollection {
    // Does compile
    fn get(&self, id: usize) -> Option<&dyn Car> {
        self.cars.get(&id).map(|c| c.as_ref())
    }

    // Does not compile
    fn get_mut(&mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&mut dyn Car> {
        self.cars.get_mut(&id).map(|c| c.as_mut())
    }
}

I know I can work around this issue with:
if let Some(car) = self.cars.get_mut(id) {
    Some(car.as_mut())
} else {
    None
}

But nonetheless, I am really confused by this and would like to know, what is going on here. I thought lifetimes do not differ between mutable and immutable references.
Playground

Interestingly, it compiles just fine if you replace dyn Car with u32: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de86aa5793103d3db0d267af0dfe76c6 So it must be something to do with the trait object.

Making the lifetime referenced by the Box explicit also appears to fix it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46fa2f7045d6e589c567add68c1bf59f

This has to do with trait object lifetime elision rules.
struct CarCollection {
    cars: HashMap<usize, Box<dyn Car>>,
}

Here, the elision rules result in this implied lifetime:
struct CarCollection {
    cars: HashMap<usize, Box<dyn Car + 'static>>,
}

Now let's look at this method:
fn get_mut(&mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&mut dyn Car>

When we desugar the elided reference lifetimes, we get this:
fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&'a mut dyn Car>

Then, by the trait object lifetime elision rules, we get something like this:
fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Car + 'a)>

This results in a lifetime mismatch when you attempt to return an Option<&mut (dyn Car + 'static)>.
Note that this works in the shared reference case because the lifetimes of shared references can be implicitly shortened, but the rules for when this can happen with exclusive references generally disallow it.  This is a complicated topic; for more information, see The Rustonomicon - Ownership - Subtyping and Variance - Variance.
The tl;dr here is that the lifetime of the trait object can be variant in the shared reference case, but not in the exclusive reference case.  Therefore, the problem is easily fixed by making the lifetime of the returned trait object explicitly 'static:
fn get_mut(&mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&mut (dyn Car + 'static)>

(Playground)
It may not be a bad idea to annotate the get method the same way, as what you have now is artificially limiting what the caller can do with the returned reference by shortening the lifetime of the trait object to that of &self.  In practice it may not actually matter, but it wouldn't hurt to make the two methods consistent.

"what you have now is artificially limiting what the caller can do with the returned reference"—I'm not sure that's true, as the trait object is only accessible behind a borrow of self (ie even you have &'a dyn (Car + 'static) you are still limited by the 'a); the reason why it's a problem for exclusive references is that you might replace the trait object behind the reference with another, and 'static is necessary to ensure the referent remains valid.

@eggyal How exactly would you replace the trait object given that they are !Sized and therefore invalid targets for assignment?

Hm, good point.  Perhaps borrowck is too pessimistic here?  One can only mutate through trait methods, which aren't constrained by the object lifetime bound... and (safe) downcasting already requires the object be 'static'.

@eggyal Probably because making an exception for this case would be quite a bit of work for arguably a very niche case, and in the future if downcasting with lifetimes can be soundly implemented then it would require rolling back anyway.
